# ag-grid: hierarchical tree of referenced nodes: how to make the referenced attributes editable?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I am testing the awesome [ag-Grid](https://ag-grid.com) component (really cool!) for a new Angular2 project. It should be used to display a CAD model structure with a "structure" (aka "tree"), and each node being the attributes of a CAD model.

Now, it is well possible to make a tree in ag-Grid. In its simpliest form, the `data` property holds the properties of the node (CAD model attributes). In this case, I can easily make the cells editable by assigning the property `editable: true` to the columnDefs.

However, the problem is, that if a CAD model is used in many places of the structure (tree), and one is edited, all others do not change.

Instead, the CAD models (the nodes) should in fact be **references** to the data, not the data itself. Ok, no problem with ag-Grid. Here you can see the comparison between a tree with **copied** nodes and a tree with **referenced** nodes:

#### Nodes are copied in the tree

ag-Grid's rowData:

```
rowData = [
  {
    data: { modelName: 'partA', weight: 12.5 }
    children: [ ... ]
  }
];
```

The ag-Grid's column definition would be:

```
{
  headerName: 'weight',
  field: 'weight',
  editable: true
}
```

#### Nodes are referenced in the treee

ag-Grid's rowData:

```
rowData = [
  {
    data: { model: MODEL_OBJECT }
    children: [ ... ]
  }
];
```

where MODEL_OBJECT is a javascript reference to the model object, which would be e.g.:

```
var modelA = { modelName: 'partA', weight: 12.5 }
```

And change the column definitions to:

```
{
  headerName: 'weight',
  valueGetter: 'data.weight',
  editable: true
}
```

See? The same properties are shown in the tree, but in fact they are fetched from the referenced POJS object. Thus, the models will be **shared** among their usages in the tree.

All well so far. But now - since there is a `valueGetter` for the column, the column `weight` is not directly editable. To be more precise, the ag-Grid allows to edit it, but it does not modify the value. Well, this is understandable since the valueGetter is acting as a mapping function which may not be "reversible" in the other direction. Consider something like 'data.firstName + data.lastName': how in the world should ag-grid know how to update `data.firstname` or `data.lastName` if the user enters another value for the column.

My question: how can I achieve the goal of having editable cells of **referenced** tree nodes? The intended effect is that if I edit the properties of a CAD model in one place of the tree, then the grid updates all other occurrences automatically, through the references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse of valueGetter in [ag-Grid](http://www.ag-grid.com) is newValueHandler. It's explained [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid-editing/index.php). You define the newValueHandler on the colDef which then gives you the freedom to do whatever you want in the value.

```
var colDef = {headerName: "Tree Value", valueGetter: "data.a+data.b", editable: true, newValueHandler: myNewValueHandler};

function myNewValueHandler(params) {
  // set the value you want in here using the params
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, that's it, thanks @Niall. I should add that because a referenced part is used in several places in the grid, it is necessary to add a `agGrid.refreshView()` in the newValueHandler, otherwise only 1 line will be edited, but the changed value will not be reflected in the other referenced places.

Comment: A complex component like datatable should better be a native angular2 component so you don't need to worry about change detection, check out PrimeNG DataTable. http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable